# uberwar cannot locate hiccup/core

Tags: clojure

I am following the tutorial from the below URL:
http://www.xuan-wu.com/2013-09-21-Basic-Web-Application-in-Clojure

but i received one error when i execute :
    `lein ring uberwar`

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate hiccup/core__init.class or hiccup/core.clj on classpath:...
```

What I read on another stackoverflow thread :

[Hiccup not working : FileNotFoundException: Could not locate ../as__init.class or ../as.clj on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888321/hiccup-not-working-filenotfoundexception-could-not-locate-as-init-class-o)

is related to the required namespace without the :as.

```
    (ns myblog.views
      (:require [hiccup.core :refer (html)]
.......
```

Also I tried to simple 'use' it:

```
    (ns myblog.views
      (:use hiccup.core)
      (:require [hiccup.form :as f]
.......
```

but i received the same error.

What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance for any hint/url!

I am copying below the project.clj file:

```
(defproject dgblog "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.9"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.0-alpha5"]
                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.25"]
                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.2"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.12"]]
  :ring {:handler dgblog.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

and the views.clj header :

```
(ns dgblog.views
  (:use hiccup.core)
  (:require
  ;; (:require [hiccup.core :refer (html)]
            [hiccup.form :as f]
            [dgblog.posts :as posts]))
```

Comment: which version of hiccup does your `project.clj` reference?

Comment: hello, and thanks for the hint. By adding the specific version in the dependency list [hiccup "1.0.5"]...fixed the issue!